# Spring AMQP retrial mechanism : how could I know if the current execution is the original one or a retrial

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Regardless the mechanism used to apply retrials on Rabbit listener, how could I know in the implementation that the current execution is the original one or a retrial after an exception.

I want to log this and also I will take action depending on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of your listener; if it's a `MessageListener` you can use `message.getMessageProperties().isRedelivered()`. If you are using a `@RabbitListener`, add `@Header(AmqpHeaders.REDELIVERED) boolean redelivered` to the method parameters.

The redelivery count is not available, just that this is a redelivery.